# Finding Landing point

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d, game-development, projectile

I am using `addforce` to throw object into the air, I want to instantiate a plane in position of landing point, how can I do that? I was thinking to calculate the landing point with Unity Physics API but I don't know how.

I have tried some code about projectiling but it won't help

```
if (other.tag == "CarPlayer")
{
    other.gameObject.GetComponentInParent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(0, 1 * power, 1 * power, ForceMode.Impulse);
}
```

I really need an algorithm to find actual point that the object is going to land

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you're gonna have to do the math yourself; Unity doesn't have a built in instant simulation of this.

There are plenty of resources online on this already, [this wiki-page on Trajectory Simulation](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=Trajectory_Simulation) for instance, which could probably help you.

If you need to calculate the force etc (the opposite of what you're asking), have a look at [this blog](https://blog.forrestthewoods.com/solving-ballistic-trajectories-b0165523348c), where the required trajectory is calculated. [Source code](https://github.com/forrestthewoods/lib_fts/blob/master/code/fts_ballistic_trajectory.cs)

The simplest answer is probably to use something like [this](https://answers.unity.com/questions/296749/display-arc-for-cannons-ball-trajectory.html):

```
public Vector3 PlotTrajectoryAtTime (Vector3 start, Vector3 startVelocity, float time) 
{
    return (start) + (startVelocity * time) + (Physics.gravity * time * time * 0.5f);
}
```

---

*(Before you start explaining PEMDAS; yes, I know the parentheses aren't needed, but I think the visual grouping gives better readability, thus easier understanding of it)*

Comment: Thank you very much , I looked at this[https://answers.unity.com/questions/296749/display-arc-for-cannons-ball-trajectory.html] and i think i should go this way .